# Why PostgreSQL is not inserting one to many relationship with hibernate using annotations?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, javafx, annotations

Here is the class I'm trying to insert:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CITA")
public class Cita implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "CITA_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "FECHA", nullable = false)
    private Date fecha;
    @Column(name = "HORA", nullable = false)
    private Time hora;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PACIENTE_ID")
    private Paciente paciente;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "EMPLEADO_ID")
    private Empleado empleado;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "CITA_TRATAMIENTO", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "CITA_ID")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "TRATAMIENTO_ID")})
    private Set<Tratamiento> listaTratamientos = new HashSet<>(0);

    public Cita() {
        fecha = null;
        hora = null;
        paciente = null;
        empleado = null;
        listaTratamientos = null;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getFecha() {
        return fecha;
    }

    public void setFecha(Date fecha) {
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }

    public Time getHora() {
        return hora;
    }

    public void setHora(Time hora) {
        this.hora = hora;
    }

    public Paciente getPaciente() {
        return paciente;
    }

    public void setPaciente(Paciente paciente) {
        this.paciente = paciente;
    }

    public Empleado getEmpleado() {
        return empleado;
    }

    public void setEmpleado(Empleado empleado) {
        this.empleado = empleado;
    }

    public Set<Tratamiento> getListaTratamientos() {
        return listaTratamientos;
    }

    public void setListaTratamientos(Set<Tratamiento> listaTratamientos) {
        this.listaTratamientos = listaTratamientos;
    }
}
```

And here is how I'm trying to save it to the database:

```
@FXML
private void registrar(ActionEvent actionEvent){
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
    Transaction tx = null;

    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();

        paciente = new Paciente();
        paciente.setNombre(txtFieldNombre.getText());
        paciente.setApellido(txtFieldApellido.getText());
        paciente.setSexo(comboBoxSexo.getValue());
        paciente.setFechaNacimiento(java.sql.Date.valueOf(datePickerFechaNacimiento.getValue()));
        paciente.setTelefono(txtFieldTelefono.getText());
        paciente.setCelular(txtFieldCelular.getText());
        Empleado empleado = ec.fromString(comboBoxEmpleadoCita.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());

        Set<Tratamiento> tratamientoSet = new HashSet<>(tableViewTratamiento.getItems());

        Cita cita = new Cita();
        cita.setHora(java.sql.Time.valueOf(localTimeTextFieldHoraCita.getLocalTime()));
        cita.setFecha(java.sql.Date.valueOf(datePickerFechaCita.getValue()));
        cita.setEmpleado(empleado);
        cita.setPaciente(paciente);
        cita.setListaTratamientos(tratamientoSet);

        session.save(cita);
        tx.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx == null) {
            tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    Notificacion.mostrarNotificacion("Registro.", "Cita con " + paciente.getNombre().toUpperCase() + " " + paciente.getApellido().toUpperCase() + " registrada!");
}
```

*Note: The other object classes I'm not showing here are working just fine. The thing is, when i save it, everything goes normal but when I check the logs it says select...., select...., ... but never insert. So its not saving it.

Any tips on why is not doing it?

Answer (score 0):

In this code:

```
Set<Tratamiento> tratamientoSet = new HashSet<>();
for (int i = 0; i < tratamientoSet.size(); i++) {
    tratamientoSet.add(tableViewTratamiento.getItems().get(i));
}
```

you create a new `HashSet`, which initially has size 0. So the `for` loop will iterate exactly zero times, and you add no elements to the set.

I think you probably meant

```
Set<Tratamiento> tratamientoSet = new HashSet<>();
for (int i = 0; i < tableViewTratamiento.getItems().size(); i++) {
    tratamientoSet.add(tableViewTratamiento.getItems().get(i));
}
```

but note that you can just do

```
Set<Tratamiento> tratamientoSet = new HashSet<>(tableViewTratamiento.getItems());
```

instead.

Comment: Yes, i put that wrong, but still that's not the problem. Anyways it wont add elements to the database. I still don't know why Postgres wont do it.

Comment: @gujoheco You're certain the set actually has elements in it?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue myself. It was a problem with one of my classes, i was sending a value no null, null. So i was making a rollback and i never printed the print-stack trace. Now its all resolve. Thanks @James_D for your time.